# Неверный дескриптор

Tags: c#

В общем, помогайте. Я только учусь, нооо...

Вот код :

```
    Console.Title = "Знакомство";
    Console.WriteLine("Давайте познакомимся");

    Console.WriteLine("Как вас зовут?");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Title = "Знакомтсво состоялось!";

    string txt = "Рад знакомству, " + name;

    Console.WriteLine(txt);
```

И он выдает ошибку о неверном дескрипторе. Указывает на

> Console.Title = " SMTH ";

Comment: ну а тип проекта какой? Окно консоли вообще присутсвует?

Comment: О господи, конечно. Просто facepalm... Спасибо)

Comment: на здоровье :-)